# gcovr: cannot analyse class under test in some cases

Tags: c++, windows, googletest, gcov, gcovr

my intention is to execute code coverage report with **gcovr** to my tests that are written with gtest framework with CMake.

```
ClassUnderTest.h:

class ClassUnderTest
{
public:
           uint8_t Start(int in_a, int in_b);

    static uint8_t MethodToTest(int a, const uint8_t *b, uint32_t c);
}
```

I have 2 test cases. One uses "TEST"s the other uses "TEST_F"s (a.k.a Test fixtures).

Test without Fixture:

```
TestCase1.cpp:

TEST (Test_Start, MethodToTest_test)
{
    ClassUnderTest       TestObj;

    EXPECT_EQ(TestObj.Start(1,2),0xFF));
}
```

Test with Fixture:

```
TestCase2.cpp:
class ClassUnderTest_Test : public ::testing::Test, public ClassUnderTest
{
public:
    virtual void SetUp();
    virtual void TearDown();

    bool TestCase2();
};

bool ClassUnderTest_Test :: TestCase2()
{
    uint8_t retval;
    retval = ClassUnderTest::MethodToTest(1,2,3);

    return retval;
}

TEST_F( ClassUnderTest_Test , MethodToTest_test )
{
    ASSERT_EQ( TestCase2(), true );
}
```

In both cases ClassUnderTest.cpp.gcno is generated and inside the data seems valid, but then when I call gcovr in a following way:

```
python C:\Python27\Scripts\gcovr --html --html-details -o output-file-name.html
```

Only the coverage of TestCase1 found in the html report, TestCase2 coverage is not visible at ClassUnderTest.cpp.

What can be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the details about the build environment and the build configuration used?

Comment: Cross-posted on the gcovr bugtracker: https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/issues/172